# Network Firewall forwarding one port to two different internal ip's based on url requested

Tags: firewall, nat, website, port-forwarding, ipcop

I have multiple websites running inside my network on 2 different machines, I need to give access to every website from the outside via a firewall router, and they need to stay on port 80. (so a request to mysite.com on port 80 goes to server 1, and a request to mysite2.com on port 80 goes to server 2). Network wise, coming in is 10 mb up/10 mb down pipe with one outside ipaddress. Internally we have around 60 to 70 devices (PC's, Mac's iPhones, iPads, and 2 servers) with exchange 2010 running on one of the servers.

Currently I have a pc running IPCop as my firewall (inherited when I got the job) and it doesn't seem to be able to do this, I know 10 years ago I was able to use a Sonic Wall device and do what I need to do here.

My question is this, can I do this with IPCop? Or what type of router/firewall would you recommend I get instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't redirect network connections based on data contained within the L7 protocol.  You'll need to install and configure some sort of HTTP proxy which can accept the request, examine the URL, and forward it to the appropriate backend.  Possible options include apache, nginx, squid, varnish, and haproxy.

Answer (score 1):

currently i maintain multiple ipcop boxes in offices and in datacenter.

in your case, if your have more than 1 fixed IPs in the WAN side, then ipcop can do this easily by port forwarding.

if you have only 1 fixed IP, then i'll suggest you to host all of your sites in a single machine, then config virtual hosts via apache.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend setting up a reverse proxy that redirects to the correct webserver depending on which site you are visiting.. you can quite easily accomplish this with nginx for example

Comment: This was already suggested. Two years ago.